# Did any player on Eagles Super Bowl winning roster play on the 04 season Super bowl?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, super-bowl

The Philadelphia Eagles beat the New England Patriots in [Super Bowl 52](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201802040nwe.htm) to win their first Super Bowl.

The last time the Eagles made it to the Super Bowl was during the 2004 season, also against the Patriots. Were there any returning Eagles from the 2004 season that were part of the team who won Super Bowl 52? If so, who are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After collating the [Eagles 2004 Roster](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/phi/2004_roster.htm) with the [Eagles 2017-2018 Roster](http://www.philadelphiaeagles.com/team/roster.html), ***There were no returning players.***

The method performed to calculate this was to prioritize the 14 years that have advanced since the 2004 roster.

Using this criteria, we can eliminate any players that were over the age of 26 on the 2004 roster due to the striking unlikelihood of any players over the age of 40 still playing other than the Kickers and Punters (both were checked, and both retired before the 2017-2018 season).

So, we are left a handful of players 26 or younger from the 2004 roster.

Of the 32 players from the 2004 Eagles roster aged 26 or younger, **none of them even made it to the 2017-2018 NFL season**.

In fact, most of the players from that great 2004 team didn't even make it out of the 2000's.

Comment: I'd like to add that the only player on either team from the 04 super bowl was Tom Brady.